# 404 error in django static files

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am new in django. I was trying to add some bootstraps in my demo project. But i am just getting 404 not found error. I have searched a lot in the web for answers which didn't help me slving my silly problem.

[image: Here is my myproject/settings.py]

[image: Here is my html file]
[image: Here is the error message]

Comment: Don't post this as screenshots are they are very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, static root is meant for production. If you want Django to pick up templates on the top level of your django project (where manage.py is), you need to add to settings.py:

> STATICFILES_DIRS = [
>       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
>      ]

STATICFILES_DIRS tells django to look templates in the paths that you add inside. For example I want django to look for templates in djang-folder/static and django-folder/other  the staticfile_dirs should look like this:

> STATICFILES_DIRS = [
>       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
>         os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "other"),
>      ]

Here is much better explained : https://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/static-files/

And here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yjInLsy6P8

And another thing: On the first line of the second screen shot  uncomment  {% load static %} , otherwise it wont pick up any static file .

Answer (score 0):

You need to include STATIC_DIRS for your local project.

You can find these settings in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/). Here are my own definitions and quotations from the documentation:

- `MEDIA_ROOT` is the folder where files uploaded using `FileField` will go.

  > Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold [user-uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/files/).
- `STATIC_ROOT` is the folder where static files will be stored after using `manage.py collectstatic`

  > The absolute path to the directory where `collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment.
  >
  > If the `staticfiles` contrib app is enabled (default) the `collectstatic` management command will collect static files into this directory. See the howto on managing static files for more details about usage.
- `STATICFILES_DIRS` is the list of folders where Django will search for additional static files aside from the `static` folder of each app installed.

  > This setting defines the additional locations the staticfiles app will traverse if the `FileSystemFinder` finder is enabled, e.g. if you use the `collectstatic` or `findstatic` management command or use the static file serving view.

In your settings, you should have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
```

...where:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

as defined in the default Django `settings.py` now.